# how to pass data from one container to another container in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap, react-router-v4

I am creating one application using react-router-v4, react-bootstrap,react-router-bootstrap so I have one `LinkContainer` on click of that I go to new page, but I want some data from the existing page to new page. what is the best way to do that? I can't pass each data in url.

Here's the button who redirects the page

```
<LinkContainer to="/mix" className="btn btn-danger">
    <input type="button" value="Mix"/>     
</LinkContainer>
```

in this component I have year, some data to use. how should I pass this data to my next container which defined in my index,js

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <HeaderContainer/>
        <Route path="/mix" component={mixContainer}/>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

EDIT 1:

adding some explanation: once it navigates it populates some data on UI. before that this data has been processed in my reducers. this processing is done based on the data I am passing through `to={{state:}}` so how can I access this data in my reducer of new page

EDIT 2:
here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ccrIaQYj27XLxg3xBWgW?p=catalogue)

Comment: Why you are not using redux store?

Comment: I am using that, but how do I pass all the data I want through router? I am using 2 different reducer for this 2 data

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "through router". But reducer maintain its store even if you change the route. So in your new page container you can subscribe to the store of your last page's redux store and you will get data of your last page there.

Comment: ok I got that one. I want to access that reducer's values in other reducer because I am doing some processing on that. can I access?if yes,how? that's actually my main pain point

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `state` nested property for `Link` component:

```
<LinkContainer 
  to={{ 
    pathname: '/mix', 
    state: { /* data you want to pass */ }
  }}
/>
```

And then in your route component:

```
// for example:
componentWillMount () {
  this.locationState = this.props.location.state
}
```

---

The other way is to use `redux` to store and retrieve data. To retrieve data from store to your component you can use [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) function from [`react-redux`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) library:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
...

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    myProperty: PropTypes.any
  }

  ...
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    myProperty: state.myReducer.someProp
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Comment: @GPorst: this helps. but if I want to access this data in my new reducers how can I access??

Comment: What do you mean by **new** reducers? Can you provide some example please?

Comment: I have added some explanation please let me know if it makes sense

Comment: Sorry, didn't get to the point, complete example would help more ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/) for instance). So you pass data via `Link` `state`?

Comment: I have added plunker and added some comments in that let me know you need more info

Comment: How does your action look like? What values do you want to be available in a different file?

Comment: current;y my action doesn't pass any argument and the data I mentioned in my plunker that both I want in my different file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152062/discussion-between-gprost-and-lowcool).